# How can I use iPhone GPS and share it with an OS X application to get live position on Mac?

Tags: macos, ios, gps, navigation

How can I use iPhone GPS and share it with an OS X application to get live position on Mac?

Note: I am looking for a way of seeing current location, live, in Google Earth, Google maps or something similar.

I assumed a configuration where I share my internet connection from iPhone and I connect a  mac to it. I know that at least the iPad can get the location when it is connected to an iPhone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think he's asking about actually using an iPhone as a GPS module for a laptop, rather than sending a location which can be viewed on a laptop.

This functionality isn't available unless you jailbreak your iPhone, then you can use xGPS or any of the similar apps on Cydia which can turn your iPhone into a bluetooth GPS module.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is weird, iPhones and iPads can find their GPS position using 3G antenna as GPS signal receiver, and by triangulation of cellphone towers position.
Also, any device with an enabled wi-fi antenna (even if it's not connected to a network) can know its location based on some Apple internet database of known wi-fi station locations.

Answer:
All you have to do is log in to iCloud.com, or to the iOS app called "find my iPhone" or "find my iPad", et voila!

Answer (score 2):

If you are an enrolled iOS developer, you could write a fairly simple iOS app that takes a GPS location and either sends this data to a server, or act as a web server itself.  Then the Mac app can get the data from that server.